# OpenCL. Weird bug with array addressing/pointers

Tags: c, linux, arrays, pointers, opencl

I have this simple kernel for testing.

```
__kernel void nfa(__global const int *a, __global int *output)
{
        output[0] = a[0];
}
```

Note: This is running on a cpu, and memory is probably on the host. It results in this error.

*** glibc detected**  ./program: malloc(): smallbin double linked list corrupted: 0x0000000000a4a540 **

I suspect somehow this is corrupting a part of the program, since it's accessing host memory. But as far I know all memory allocated correctly. It is on the stack, but stays in scope while running.

However if I do this:

```
   __kernel void nfa(__global const int *a, __global int *output)
    {
            a = a;
            output[0] = a[0];
    }
```

It results in the answer 2, which is correct since a is an array with [2, 4, 8];

An allocation to its self fixed the issue...

This is also fine, resulting in 4.

```
   __kernel void nfa(__global const int *a, __global int *output)
    {
            output[0] = a[1];
    }
```

It seems as though just accessing a[0], without assigning to its self causes the problem.

Does anyone know what's going on?

I'm on linux with AMD OpenCL Drivers(With an intel CPU, but I have a AMD Card).

Edit:

The code the buffer is created with(Condensed down, there is other code between the array and buffer):

```
int a[3];
a[0] = 2;
a[1] = 4;
a[2] = 8;

cl::Buffer bufferA = cl::Buffer(context, CL_MEM_READ_ONLY | CL_MEM_USE_HOST_PTR , sizeof(int) * 3, &a);
```

Comment: Did you allocate the memory with malloc, or with clCreateBuffer()?  I believe the latter is required, even if you're on a CPU device.

Comment: Memory is on the stack. clCreateBuffer is used(Well its equivalent i'm using c++ bindings), and the clCreateBuffer method is passed the pointer to the array, it uses the flag "CL_MEM_USE_HOST_PT". As far as i'm aware this can result in either using the memory directly, and copying it to the GPU. Since i'm not using the GPU, it is on the host.

Comment: Can we see your clSetKernelArg() call?

Comment: Why don't you test with CL_MEM_COPY_HOST_PTR? I mean, I don't see how you are making sure that OpenCL doesn't access the array after the function returned?

Answer (score 1):

I may be wrong (I've not used C++ OpenCL but I believe its roughly the same as the C bindings) but I believe:

The last type the argument to the call to cl::Buffer is void*. What you want is a pointer to the block of memory you're passing in, in this case the array (which is auto converted to pointer because arrays). You've passed in a *pointer* to the array (ie pointer to pointer), which gets cast to void* quietly by the compiler. This means, you end up copying the array pointer, and then whatever happens to be after that by 2 ints in memory. I can imagine this causing poor results

I'm not sure why a=a or output = a[1] would fix it since I have no experience doing CPU OpenCL and I'm not sure how the specifics work. On a GPU you might be able to explain it away as the device caching the memory for performance reasons, and thus preventing the memory invalidation from occuring (or something)

Edit: Whoops, just realised how old this is, I should learn to read better